# NodeJs: How to Load a Website without waiting for Long Query to Finish?

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I have a node js file that queries a sql server table that takes a about 17 seconds to run (huge table - long query). I would like my website to run without waiting for the query to finish. How would the resulting code be different from what I have?

```js
app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
      await sql.connect(config);
    

      const superLongQuery = await sql.query`select something from somethingElse`;     
     
      res.render("index",{superQuery: superLongQuery})
   
});
```

Comment: load the data asynchronously with [ajax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29)

Comment: any solutions with node js?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what module you're using but I assume for `sql` you just need to connect to connect to it once. Put the `sql.connect(config);` outside of express. When you put it in the `app.get` every new request to that endpoint would be connecting to sql which just wastes too much resources and performance.

Comment: the query needs to be loaded each time because it changes everyday

Comment: may I ask what node module it is? When you connect to the sql database it should detect the changes even if it's connected before the changes were made.

Comment: sure, is mssql to connect to sql server 2012

Comment: I've heard about React’s useEffect Hook to possibly accomplish what I'm looking for, but not sure how to use it